# Writing shell scripts that will run on any shell (using multiple shebang lines?)

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, zsh, bash-scripting

I've just started getting deeper into shell scripting, and I've always just thrown my script in a file, marked it `chmod +x` and then done `/path/to/script.sh` and let whatever interpreter is the default have its way with it, which I assumed was zsh because that's what I used for my shell. Apparently it seems that it's just `/bin/sh` by default, even if I execute the script from a zsh prompt, because I started putting zsh-specific stuff in my scripts and it's failing unless I run `zsh /path/to/script.sh`.

To get to the point, here are my questions:

1. Which shell executes scripts when there's no shebang line (`#!/path/to/shell`) at the beginning? I assume `/bin/sh` but I can't confirm.
2. What is considered "best practices" in terms of writing shell scripts that will run on any platform? (ok, this is sort of open-ended)
3. Is it possible to write a script that tries to use zsh and falls back to bash if zsh is not available? I've tried putting two shebang lines, like below, but it just errors with `bad interpreter: /bin/zsh: no such file or directory` out if I try it on a machine without zsh.

   `#!/bin/zsh`

   `#!/bin/bash`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Which shell executes scripts when there's no shebang line (#!/path/to/shell) at the beginning? I assume /bin/sh but I can't confirm.

The kernel refuses to execute such scripts and returns ENOEXEC, so the exact behavior depends on the program you run such a script *from*.

- bash 4.2.39 – uses itself
- busybox-ash 1.20.2 – uses itself
- dash 0.5.7 – runs /bin/sh
- fish 1.23.1 – complains about ENOEXEC, then blames the wrong file
- AT&T ksh 93u+2012.08.01 – uses itself
- mksh R40f – runs /bin/sh
- pdksh 5.2.14 – runs /bin/sh
- sh-heirloom 050706 – uses itself
- tcsh 6.18.01 – runs /bin/sh
- zsh 5.0.0 – runs /bin/sh
- cmd.exe 5.1.2600 – looks at you funny.

In *glibc*, functions `execv()` or `execve()` just return ENOEXEC. But `execvp()` hides this error code and automatically invokes /bin/sh. (This is documented in [exec(3p)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man3/exec.3posix.html).)

> What is considered "best practices" in terms of writing shell scripts that will run on any platform? (ok, this is sort of open-ended)

Either stick to `sh` and only POSIX-defined features, or just go full *bash* (which is widely available) and mention it in your requirements if distributing it.

(Now that I think of it, Perl – or perhaps Python – would be even more portable, not to mention having a better syntax.)

**Always** add the shebang line. If using bash or zsh, use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` instead of hardcoding the shell's path. (However, the POSIX shell is guaranteed to be at `/bin/sh`, so skip `env` in that case.)

(Unfortunately, even `/bin/sh` is not always the same. The GNU *autoconf* program has to deal with [many different quirks](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Portable-Shell.html).)

> Is it possible to write a script that tries to use zsh and falls back to bash if zsh is not available? I've tried putting two shebang lines, like below, but it just errors with *bad interpreter: /bin/zsh: no such file or directory* out if I try it on a machine without zsh.

There can only be one shebang line; everything after the newline character isn't even read by the kernel, and treated as a comment by shells.

It's *possible* to write a script that runs as `#!/bin/sh`, checks which shell is available, and runs `exec zsh "$0" "$@"` or `exec bash "$0" "$@"` depending on the result. However, the syntax used by bash and zsh is so different in various places that I would **not recommend doing this** for your own sanity.

Comment: Amazingly thorough answer. Not sure where you got that list of behaviors, but props for that! I guess I'll just add the `#!/usr/bin/env bash` to my scripts & target them for bash because it's widely available. Bizarre that zsh defaults to sh, but I guess it's for compatibility.

Comment: @SWrobel: I just tested these shells while writing the answer. And yes, it's mostly for compatibility: [before `#!` was introduced](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/), almost all scripts were written for the Bourne shell.

Comment: how did you trace what each shell was actually calling when it received ENOEXEC?

Comment: @SWrobel: Using `strace -f -e fork,clone,execve`. Some shells went on to exec `/bin/sh` after failure; others interpreted the script themselves.

Comment: @SWrobel: Another method is to run a script that consists of `readlink /proc/$$/exe`.

Comment: @SWrobel: ...ah, and note that `strace` displays kernel syscalls, not (similarly-named) libc functions.

Comment: See also [Stéphane Chazelas’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/373223/80216#373294) to [Which shell interpreter runs a script with no shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/373223/80216) (cross-site duplicate of sub-question #1)

Comment: Precision: `/bin/sh` doesn't have to be POSIX compliant. POSIX does not specify the paths of commands. On Solaris 10 and older, `/bin/sh` was a Bourne shell, so not a POSIX shell. The POSIX shell  was (and still is in Solaris 11 where /bin/sh is ksh93, so a lot more POSIX compliant than the Bourne shell) in `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh`.

Comment: For `csh` and `tcsh`, the behaviour depends on whether the script starts with `#` (in which case they invoke themselves instead of sh to interpret the script). That goes back to the time when csh supported comments but not the Bourne shell, so a `#` was a hint that it was a csh script.

Answer (score 2):

1) The current shell you're running in. (whatever shell that may be)

2) Stick with the same shell type (bash/dash/ash/csh/whatever your flavor) and make sure your "supported platforms" install the shell you wish to use by default.  Also, try to use commonly available commands on systems.  Avoid machine-specific options.

3) There's not really an "if-then-else" logic to the `interpreter directive`.  You should specify a shell that should exist on all systems you wish to support... i.e. `#!/bin/bash` or specify a generic `#!/bin/sh` as long as your script is fairly generic across all shells.