# bash --norc failed when I want my test script with clean output

Tags: bash

I want my test script could be run without initial startup scripts.

I found the option "--norc" can not work.
The bash version is 4.2.0(2)

my ~/.bashrc contains

```
echo "in .bashrc"
```

I want to bash --norc -x test.sh output a content without .bashrc.

```
$ touch test.sh
$ bash -x test.sh
+ echo 'in .bashrc'
in .bashrc

$ bash --norc -x test.sh
+ echo 'in .bashrc'
in .bashrc
```

I found this problem only occurs on my Embedded system. The real Linux does not have such problem.

Comment: Does "echo $BASH_ENV" produce any output? The value of that parameter is used as the name of a file to source even for non-interactive shells; perhaps it is set to ".bashrc" somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, non-interactive shells aren’t supposed to read `.bashrc` at all.  So your question shouldn’t be “Why is `--norc` not working?”; your question should be “Why is this *shell script* (non-interactive shell) reading `.bashrc` in the first place?”.  One possibility is that you have a `BASH_ENV` environment variable that is set to `~/.bashrc`.  If that’s not it, I don’t know, but here are some things you might want to try:

- If your script isn’t doing anything `bash`-specific, try running it with `sh`; i.e., `sh -x test.sh`.
- Create a `testrc` file with an `echo` in it, and say `bash -–rcfile testrc -x test.sh`.
- Say `bash -–rcfile /dev/null -x test.sh`.
- Any and all of the above without `-x`. 
  (This shouldn’t make a difference, but this problem already doesn’t make any sense.)
- Run the script as a normal program: `chmod +x test.sh` and then just `test.sh`
  (or `./test.sh`, if you don’t have `.` in your search path). 
  (You will need to have `#!/bin/bash`, `#!/bin/sh`, `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, or something equivalent as the first line of `test.sh`, but that’s a good practice anyway –– see [grawity’s discussion](https://superuser.com/a/503009/150988).) 
  (But this shouldn’t make a difference, either.)
- And really, you should do this first, but I didn’t want to annoy you and make you ignore the rest of my answer: Make *sure* the problem is what you say it is.  Check, double-check, and triple-check `test.sh` for any `source` or `.` commands that might (maybe indirectly) pull in `.bashrc`.  Similarly, see whether it calls any other scripts that might be doing it.  Verify that the `in .bashrc` message is really coming from `.bashrc` –– try renaming `.bashrc` (e.g., to `.bashrc.hold`, or whatever) and/or `chmod`ing it to 0, and try again.

Comment: I've simplified my question, so I just use touch to create empty shell script. I've tested all your suggestion before asking.  This is very strange. I'm testing it in embedded system.  But when I test on Linux box, it seems work.

Comment: The major reason is 'BASH_ENV', I unset it, then it works.

Answer (score 1):

`--norc` only applies to interactive shells; you are starting a non-interactive shell by providing the `test.sh` argument. Try adding the `-i` flag as well to force an interactive shell. (Note: this may leave you in the new shell after `test.sh` completes; I haven't tested.)

Comment: That doesn’t make much sense.  The reason `--norc` applies only to interactive shells is that non-interactive shells aren’t supposed to read `.bashrc` at all.  Sure, I’m interested in hearing whether specifying `-i` fixes the problem, but it seems like a peculiar way to try.

Comment: Good point; I missed the forest for the trees. I guess the real question is, why is he seeing output from .bashrc even without --norc.