# Default shell for running scripts (w/o shebang) in macos?

Tags: macos, mac, shell, zsh, osx-mavericks

I have ZSH as default shell in MacOS, everything is working fine. ZSH is installed as brew package, Ive set default shell in my account, new shell is listed in `/etc/shells`... everything is set, like I've said.

I have some shell scripts in which I use some commands from zsh, like `print`. When I execute the script from command line, the `print` command is not recognized and the script fails.

This script does **not** have the shebang line. When I put the shebang line for zsh, then everything works; the `print` command is working.

Since I am using only ZSH, is it possible to set default shell for *running scripts*, so I don't have to put shebang line in my .zsh scripts?

Or is it possible to associate `.zsh` extension to ZSH shell execution?

Comment: How exactly are you executing those scripts from the command like if they don't have a shebang line?

Comment: By script name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *Z shell* uses `/bin/sh` if you run an executable script without shebang line (see `man zshmisc`, section COMMAND EXECUTION or check out [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/503009/195224) for a comprehensive list). This seems hard-coded. So, if you don't want to use the unix-way (add shebang line), you can use a socalled *suffix alias* in the Z shell to execute all files with a certain extension with a certain program. In your case

```
alias -s zsh=zsh
```

should do the trick. The general form is (as the above example is not so clear):

```
alias -s extension=program
```

The man page explains how this works:

> If  the  -s  flag is present, define a suffix alias: if the command word on a command line is in the form `text.name`, where text
>   is any non-empty string, it is replaced by the text `value text.name`.  Note that name is treated as a literal string, not  a 
>   pattern.
>
> A trailing space in value is not special in this case.  For example,
>
> ```
> alias -s ps=gv
> ```
>
> will cause the command `*.ps` to be expanded to `gv *.ps`.  As alias expansion is carried out earlier than globbing, the `*.ps` will
>                 then be expanded.  Suffix aliases constitute a different name space from other aliases (so in the above example it is still
>   possible
>                 to create an alias for the command ps) and the two sets are never listed together.

---

If you want to use scripts that are located somewhere in your `$PATH`, use

```
alias -s zsh="zsh -o PATH_SCRIPT"
```

This enables the option `PATH_SCRIPT`:

> If the option PATH_SCRIPT is set, and the file name does not contain a directory path (i.e. there is no `/' in the name), first the current directory and then the command path given by the variable  PATH
>          are searched for the script.

Please note, that the current directory is searched for the script, even if `.` is not in your `PATH`!

Comment: When I set `alias -s zsh=/usr/local/bin/zsh` and invoke a script that is on path, but not in current folder, then the system "can't open input file", which makes sense. So this is a step forward, but not yet  final solution...

Comment: Or in the other words: if argument is file name that is on the PATH, how to find it's absolute path?

Comment: @IgorSpasic: I extended my answer accordingly.