# Cron scheduled backup script not working or writing to log file

Tags: ubuntu, bash, backup, cron, duplicity

I have a duplicity backup script set to run once per day through the root cron tab.

I set it up like this:

```
sudo crontab -e -u root
```

and added the line:

```
00 03   *   *   *  root   /home/[myusername]/Scripts/Backups/DuplicityBackup.sh
```

the script has commands to write to a text file like this:

```
echo "Creating backup of data directory"
PASSPHRASE='[mypassword]' duplicity /usr/share/nginx/data file:///dysonbackup/datadir &>> /home/[myusername]/Scripts/Backups/backup_logs/data_backup_log.txt

echo "Done"
```

Running the script itself as root starts the backup and writes to the text file.

Running

```
sudo crontab -l
```

shows it listed

Running

```
grep DuplicityBackup.sh /var/log/syslog
```

shows

```
May 28 03:00:01 [myservername] CRON[89749]: (root) CMD (root   /home/[myusername]/Scripts/Backups/DuplicityBackup.sh)
```

so I am assuming it at least triggered to run, but there is no new information on the text file.

And it does not appear that the duplicity backup is running as there are no new files in the backup directory.

Ubuntu 20.04

duplicity 0.8.12

Comment: Did you look in root's mail for any output?

Comment: I can't find the root mail. cd /var/mail/root
bash: cd: /var/mail/root: No such file or directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Excessive field

`sudo crontab -e -u root` edits crontab for the user root. This is different than the system-wide crontab (`/etc/crontab`). The former uses entries in a form of

```
m h  dom mon dow  command
```

and the latter uses

```
m h  dom mon dow  user  command
```

You used the latter syntax where you should have used the former. The tool tried to run

```
root   /home/myusername/Scripts/Backups/DuplicityBackup.sh
```

Solution: either move your job to `/etc/crontab` as-is; or fix the syntax by removing `root`.

If it's not enough then keep reading.

---

#### No shebang?

Does `DuplicityBackup.sh` contain a [shebang](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87600/108618) that specifies Bash as the interpreter?

cron will run `/home/myusername/Scripts/Backups/DuplicityBackup.sh` in `sh`. If there is no shebang [the situation is complicated in general](https://superuser.com/a/503009/432690), but `sh` should run it in `sh`, regardless of who provides `sh` (there are different implementations, compare [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/976504/693277)).

When you run the script from Bash, it gets run in Bash.

`&>>` you used is a bashism. In Bash `&>> file` is equivalent to `>> file 2>&1` and this is what you want. In `sh` it's equivalent to `& >> file` and this is not what you want.

Solution: use a shebang.

---

#### Inaccessible `/home/myusername`?

`/home/myusername` may not be available because:

- `/home/myusername` is automatically unmounted when `myusername` logs out (especially possible if it's encrypted);
- or `/home/myusername` is mounted as [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) without `allow_other` and therefore cron running as root cannot access it;
- or cron is run by `systemd` and the service (`cron.service`) uses `ProtectHome=` or `InaccessiblePaths=` to restrict access to `/home/myusername` (not likely though).

Solution: do not use `/home/myusername` with cron jobs run by root.

Comment: Thanks. I will try your first suggestion and see if it runs in the morning. I do have : #!/bin/bash at he start of the .sh file. If it doesn't run I will try your 3rd suggestion.

Comment: The first suggestion did the trick. Thanks!