# Execute sudo command in cronjob (vestacp/ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

Is it possible to add cron command like "sudo systemctl restart exim4"? Usually in cronjob's list there's a path to the execution file, but looks like vestacp has list of other commands which is not included like "systemctl {action} {service}".
Do I need to make some kind of file with mentioned command execution? Because I believe cronjob with command "sudo systemctl restart exim4" not going to work.

Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, [`sudo` may require a tty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/122616/108618), I believe it won't get a tty from cron. But if you can `sudo` then probably you can edit the system-wide crontab (`/etc/crontab`; or put a file in `/etc/cron.d`). This is a way to make cron restart a system-wide service, *not* with `sudo` from a user's crontab.

E.g. in `/etc/crontab` in my Debian I have put:

```
47 2    * * 2,6 root    systemctl restart transmission-daemon.service
```

to restart `transmission` twice a week (I have my reasons) and I know it works.

Note the system-wide crontab requires an extra field (`root` in the example above) and [it's different than root's crontab](https://superuser.com/a/1555845/432690).